# Get facebook users that shared the same URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to know if that is a way to get a list of facebook users who had shared urls from my website.

What a want is, using a given URL, get user's name and pic. I already tried with the fql:

```
SELECT pic_square, username, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (
    SELECT owner FROM link WHERE url="http://someurl.html" AND owner IN (
        SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
    ) limit 6
)
```

It seems to work but only for my friends. A want to have all users that shared it.

Any idea?
Thanks anyway...

Comment: now that would be a major privacy problem, so i am pretty sure (and hope) it is not possible...

Comment: You're right @luschn! It just works for user or friends, and requires user authentication within a app.